# How can I avoid pictures appearing under footnotes?

Tags: graphics, footnotes

I found this problem when writing a document with a lot of pictures. I used `htb` option of `figure` environment, and some of the pictures appeared under footnotes.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    test\footnote{test}
    \begin{figure}[b]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{test.jpg}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You can use any picture as `test.jpg`.

The result is like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=5in,paperwidth=3in]{geometry}
%smaller dimensions for testing purposes
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    test\footnote{test}
    \begin{figure}[b]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{8251.png}%or whatever image you like
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]